# do [the/some] online banking vs. do [the/some] grocery shopping

Tags: phrase-usage, definite-article, determiners, quantifiers

In the following phrases, is it optional to include the bracketed part?

> do [the/some] online banking

> do [the/some] grocery shopping

Answer (score 1):

It's optional in the sense that the sentences are grammatical without those parts.
But they don't mean the same things.

1. *do some online banking/grocery shopping* means do a part (not all) of whatever online banking
   **or** grocery shopping you have to do
2. *do the online banking/grocery shopping* means do all of your online banking **or** grocery shopping
3. *do online banking/grocery shopping* means use a computer instead of going to the bank
   **or** do some/all of your grocery shopping

Comment: Is "do shopping" (without "the" or "some") also grammatical?

Comment: grammatical, but not usuallly idiomatic

Comment: @JamesK Thank you. Is "He's planning to do grocery shopping this afternoon" (without "the" or suchlike) idiomatic?

Comment: "go grocery shopping" is better. but "go to the supermarket" is or similar is culturally more common.