# doing [determiner] grocery shopping

Tags: idiomatic-language, determiners, quantifiers

Pedagogical materials commonly advise adding a determiner or quantity word to "do [the/one's/some] Ving." However, in the following passage, "doing grocery shopping" does not have a determiner in it. Is it an error? If it's idiomatic, how do we reconcile such examples with pedagogical materials?

> The man said he bought the Big Wednesday ticket to pass the time when his wife was shopping last week. His wife was **doing grocery shopping** again when he returned to the counter and found out he had become a multi-millionaire.

https://www.stuff.co.nz/editors-picks/10472963/You-ve-just-won-20-million

In Michael Swan's Practical English Usage, he offers the following examples:

> Could you do **the** shopping for me?

> I hate doing **the** ironing.

If these sentences cannot have "the" left out, why does the first quoted example not have a determiner?

Comment: It would be equally correct to write either **doing grocery shopping** or **doing her grocery shopping**.  In the first instance, the **her** would be understood.

Comment: @RonaldSole - she might have been doing grocery shopping for her husband and herself, and possibly family members too, so it might not be completely appropriate to call it 'her' grocery shopping.

Comment: @RonaldSole What about "I hate doing [] ironing"?

Comment: In Michael Swan's examples, _the shopping_ means 'buying the supplies required by a household at a particular time' and _the ironing_ 'ironing the creased garments from a particular load of washing'. The activities _per se_ would be simply _shopping_ and _ironing_.

Comment: @KateBunting I had thought about that. However, in the first quoted example ("His wife was doing grocery shopping again ..."), the person could be equally said to have been buying the supplies required by a household at a particular time, but there is no "the" used.

Comment: We don't know why the reporter left out the determiner. Maybe New Zealand usage is different. As Ronald says, _the_ or _her_ is 'understood'.

Comment: Compare [your earlier question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/315286/do-the-some-online-banking-vs-do-the-some-grocery-shopping?rq=1).

Comment: @KateBunting That thread doesn't contain real-life examples.

Comment: I'm thinking about whether the "grocery," as a modifier, can assume the function of a determiner, just as it's okay to say "listen to English radio," where "English" replaces "the" as it's used in "listen to the radio."

Comment: @KateBunting - there is also an issue (maybe?) of sex-role stereotyping, if I can raise that here. Why should it be a default supposition that the wife does the grocery shopping? I do **our** grocery shopping - I have a sharp eye for a ripe avocado.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I only used _her_ because a woman shopper was mentioned in the original passage - no stereotyping involved.

Comment: It's correct to me. It means exactly the same as, "*... doing **some** grocery shopping.*"

Comment: @gotube Do you find "Could you **do shopping** for me?" okay?

Comment: @Apollyon Hrm.... I'm on the fence. It sounds odd, but I can imagine at least one very specific context where it makes sense. Like, say the speaker is badly injured, and is going through a list of things, asking their friend if they can do these things for them: "Could you cook for me? Could you do gardening for me? Could you do shopping for me?" Even then, "*Could you **go** shopping for me?*" would be a bit more natural, but "do shopping" would be fine.

Comment: @gotube Is "go shopping" okay in your example because it has been primed by "cook for me"?

Comment: @Apollyon No. It's OK because "go shopping" is a much more common expression than "do (some) shopping". It's not related to "cook for me".

Comment: @gotube Sorry, I asked about the wrong expression. I should have asked, "Is '**do shopping**" okay in your example because it has been primed by 'cook for me'?

Comment: @Apollyon Maybe. When I was writing that example, I put "Could you cook for me" first in that list because it made "do shopping" sound better. That's not to say it's not OK without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see much wrong with saying "doing grocery shopping" without a determiner.

But as a native speaker I don't think I'd put it that way (though undoubtedly some do).

There is absolutely nothing wrong with leaving out the ***doing*** and saying - ***...his wife was still grocery shopping.***

That would be my choice of words, especially if no obvious determiner were available..

Comment: Thank you. Does "do shopping' sound okay to you? For example, "The man said he bought the Big Wednesday ticket to pass the time when his wife was shopping last week. His wife was **doing shopping** again when he returned to the counter and found out he had become a multi-millionaire."

Comment: @Apollyon There isn't much wrong with it - and everyone knows what it means. But I think that most British people would say simply "...his wife was shopping again, when..." or "his wife was doing the shopping again, when..."

Comment: Thank you. Learners who say "do shopping" can certainly get their idea across, but I'm wondering if it's as idiomatic as "do the shopping" or "do grocery shopping." If there is a difference in acceptability, even a small one, it's something worth our attention.

Comment: It is difficult for anyone who learns a language in adulthood ever to be able to perfect their idioms in the way a native speaker can. I know this from a lifetime of trying to be a French speaker.

Answer (score 1):

It is acceptable.

Pedacological materials emphasise this point because it is a rather illogical use of "the". It does mean "the shopping that is required to be done at this particular point in time", but it is not very obvious that "the" should be idiomatic in "I'm doing the shopping".

But when you don't mean "the required shopping", and especially here with an adjective to clarify what type of shopping we are talking about, the word "the" is not needed.

Another example examples:

> I enjoy doing clothes shopping, much more than shopping for groceries.

In most cases where "doing shopping" is used, you could replace with the verb "shopping", and that would be my preferred paraphrase:

> His wife was grocery shopping again when he returned to the counter

> His wife was shopping for groceries again when he returned to the counter

Comment: Thank you. Does "do shopping' sound okay to you? For example, "The man said he bought the Big Wednesday ticket to pass the time when his wife was shopping last week. His wife was **doing shopping** again when he returned to the counter and found out he had become a multi-millionaire."

Comment: I'm eager to see if there's any difference between "do shopping" and "do grocery shopping" in acceptability.